# How to delete a Line in MFC

Tags: c++, mfc, gdi

I'm writing an MFC Application like Paint. 
I draw a line (by hold and move the mouse) in two steps:

*Step 1: Handle WM_LBUTTONDOWN and get startPoint.*

*Step 2: Handle WM_MOUSEMOVE (with MK_LBUTTON) to get endPoint, and draw a line from startPoint to endPoint using LineTo() function.*

But in Step 2, it draws one line when receive WM_MOUSEMOVE, so creates too much lines. I want to delete old line and draw new one in this step. (Only one line is drawn when receive WM_LBUTTONUP).
Can you help me please. Thank everyone. Sorry if my English is so bad.

Answer (score 1):

in WM_LBUTTONDOWN, set a new member variable m_pMouseObject to NULL.

in WM_MOUSEMOVE, if m_pMouseObject == NULL, set m_pMouseObject to a newly created line object, otherwise keep modifying m_pMouseObject as the mouse moves.

in WM_LBUTTONUP, create your definitive line object from m_pMouseObject and set m_pMouseObject = NULL.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't know if I "definitive line object from m_pMouseObject" (call Invalidate()), it will erase all shape I have drawn in the client area, won't it? I am new in MFC, I need your help. Thank you very much.

Comment: If you follow the standard way of painting (when you receive WM_PAINT and not on mouse move), invalidate will paint the object properly -- you would also need to invalidate the object's rectangle during mouse move

Answer (score 0):

In WM_MOUSEMOVE set the endPoint variable but do not draw. Instead call Invalidate. That will cause an erase and redraw. So in OnPaint/OnDraw draw a line from startPoint to endPoint.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am new in MFC. If I call Invalidate(), OnPaint() will erase all in the client area ? But I only want to erase the old Line in the previous WM_MOUSEMOVE message and draw current line. Can you help me please?

Comment: If you want to control the line color and width then it must be done as I described. There is another way that uses an XOR pen, frequently used to let the user drag a rubber line or rectangle. An XOR pen can be erased by redrawing it. To research this method look up SetROP2 in the MSDN.

Comment: I have some small questions and I need your help. Can you give me yahoo ID or something else which I can live chat with you? Thank you.